# Copy and flipping a 3D Unity asset in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an asset loaded from an asset bundle. I had the idea to add the same asset, but flipped, and wanted to try to do it without actually going and adding an otherwise identical asset to the bundle.

```
FlippedApartmentPrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(FlippedApartmentPrefab.transform.localScale.x * -1,
            FlippedApartmentPrefab.transform.localScale.y,
            FlippedApartmentPrefab.transform.localScale.z);
```

So I load it twice

```
ApartmentPrefab = assetBundle.LoadAsset("assets/workspace/Apartment.prefab") as GameObject;
FlippedApartmentPrefab = assetBundle.LoadAsset("assets/workspace/Apartment.prefab") as GameObject;
```

But these are the same object. It apparently remembers that the asset has been loaded and points me at the original. That's a great optimization, except that now the flipped and non-flipped ones aren't any different.

```
ApartmentPrefab == FlippedApartmentPrefab //True
```

Is there a way to create another instance of the GameObject that can be manipulated independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) to clone the prefab.

```
var prefab = assetBundle.LoadAsset("assets/workspace/Apartment.prefab") as GameObject;
ApartmentPrefab = Object.Instantiate(prefab);
FlippedApartmentPrefab = Object.Instantiate(prefab);
```

Comment: btw whenever available I would rather use the generic variants `var prefab = assetBundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>(".....");`